# What does ま？ mean?

Tags: meaning, slang, internet-slang

## Japanese

"ま？"と話している人を見たことがあります。あれっ？と思ったのですが、会話が成立しています。何かの略語だと思いますが、分かりません。もちろん辞書にも載っていません。

ま？の意味は何でしょうか。

## English

I have seen people who say "ま？" I thought *what?*, but they were establishing decent conversation. I think it is an abbreviation, but I'm not sure. Of course it's not listed in my dictionary.

What does ま mean?

Comment: すでに説明されていますが、ちょっと追加解説を。 これはネット用語で、主に2chやツイッターで使われています。
理解されない可能性はありますし、寒いだけなので日常会話で使用しない方がいいですね。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

これのことでしょうか。

[「マ？」の意味は？「こマ？」「そマ？」もあわせて解説](https://kw-note.com/internet-slang/ma/)

> まず「マ」ですが、これは「マジ」(本気)の略です。
>   クエスチョンマークを付けて「マ？」という様に書き込まれていたら、この意味は「マジ？」ということです。

「マジ？」という聞き返しが、軽い確認にまで多用されるようになった結果、限界まで短縮されてしまったのだと思います。

個人的には、この記事にも書かれている通り、「マ」単体よりもむしろ「こマ？」（これマジ？）等二文字合わせた形で見たり使ったりするのが圧倒的に多い気がします。

Comment: 都会に行ったときに聞いて(田舎者というのもあり)意味不明だったので。。。有難うございます。

Comment: @sun-solar-arrow 都会というよりもネット界隈ですかね…。あと「聞いて」と書かれましたが口に出して言う人は相当珍しいと思います（よほどネットスラングを使い慣れてる層なのかも）

Answer (score 3):

## Japanese

"ま？"は"マジ？"の略だと思います。つまり、"Really?"です。

書くときはカタカナで"マ？"と書きます。

## English

I think "ま？" is an abbreviation for "マジ？". So its meaning is "Really?"

It is usually written in katakana, as "マ？"